# accordionPanel - multiline header in tab

Tags: primefaces, accordion, multiline

I would like to make accordion component with tab that has multiline headers.

Is it possible to make tab header multiline in accordion component?

I am using newest Primefaces 4.0-rc1.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can define title section of `<p:tab>` by nesting `<f:facet name="title">`, where you can put your components. The example:

```
<p:tab>
    <f:facet name="title">
        <div>First line</div>
        <br/>
        <div>Second line</div>
    </f:facet>
    ...
<p:tab>
```